# angular md-fab-toolbar follow scroll

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I have a page with 3 cards, in one of these I have a md-fab-toolbar.

```
<md-card class="card-width">
          <md-toolbar class="md-hue-2" layout-align="center start" layout-padding>
            <span>{{cardName}}</span>
          </md-toolbar>
          <md-card-content>
            <div>
                        <p>Scroll</p>
                        <p>Scroll</p>
                        <p>Scroll</p>
                        <p>Scroll</p>
                        <p>Scroll</p>
                        <p>Scroll</p>
                        <p>Scroll</p>
                        <p>Scroll</p>
                        <p>Scroll</p>
                        <p>Scroll</p>
                        <p>Scroll</p>
                        <p>Scroll</p>
                        <p>Scroll</p>
                        <p>Scroll</p>
                        <p>Scroll</p>
                        <p>Scroll</p>
                        <p>Scroll</p>
                        <p>Scroll</p>
                        <p>Scroll</p>
                    </div>
                    <md-fab-toolbar md-direction="left" class="md-fab-bottom-right">
                        <md-fab-trigger class="align-with-text">
                            <md-button aria-label="menu" class="md-fab md-primary">
                                <md-icon>menu</md-icon>
                            </md-button>
                        </md-fab-trigger>
                        <md-toolbar>
                            <md-fab-actions class="md-toolbar-tools">
                                <md-button aria-label="comment" class="md-icon-button">
                                    <md-icon>magnify</md-icon>
                                </md-button>
                                <md-button aria-label="comment" class="md-icon-button">
                                    <md-icon>magnify</md-icon>
                                </md-button>
                                <md-button aria-label="comment" class="md-icon-button">
                                    <md-icon>magnify</md-icon>
                                </md-button>
                                <md-button aria-label="comment" class="md-icon-button">
                                    <md-icon>magnify</md-icon>
                                </md-button>
                                <md-button aria-label="comment" class="md-icon-button">
                                    <md-icon>magnify</md-icon>
                                </md-button>
                            </md-fab-actions>
                        </md-toolbar>
                    </md-fab-toolbar>
          </md-card-content>
        </md-card>
```

Check this codepen:
http://codepen.io/marcusdacoregio/pen/ZpdQwa

I want the md-fab-toolbar to follow the scroll and not to stay absolute position.
I can't get this behavior, do you guys can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want? - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/edwbzd?editors=1010#0)

Markup (relevant)

```
<md-content layout="column">
    <md-card class="card-width">
        <md-toolbar class="md-hue-2" layout-align="center start" layout-padding>
            <span>{{cardName}}</span>
        </md-toolbar>
        <md-card-content layout="column">
            <div id="myList">
```

CSS

```
#myList {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer. Almost this, i want something like this [codepen](http://codepen.io/mckenzielong/pen/WvNQox). Wherever my scroll is, i want the fab button on the right bottom.

Comment: @MarcusDacorréggio See the updated CodePen and answer.

Comment: thank you very much. This is the behavior that I was looking for.

Comment: @MarcusDacorréggio Glad to help. Good question.